# how to get power set of an array in python without using binary array

Tags: python

i have used the binary array to get the power set.it does the job in O(n^2) but i want to know any other more efficient way to get power set or any other way to get that without using arrays of bits.

```
ar=[1,2,3]
binary=[]
for i in range(1,(len(ar)**2)-1):
    if len(bin(i)[2:])<=len(ar)-1:
        binary.append((((len(ar))-len(bin(i)[2:]))*'0'+bin(i)[2:]))
    else:
        binary.append((bin(i)[2:]))
for i in binary:
    print('(',end='')
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if i[j]=='1':
            print(ar[j],end=' ')
    print(')',end='')
```

Comment: You don't have an array, and certainly not an array of bits.

Comment: i mean binary list @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: A power set has `n^2` elements. I think `O(n^2)` is fairly good.